# It is possible to add text below checklist using dialog linux command?

Tags: linux, dialog, checklistbox

I have created a checklist using linux dialog command and I want to add some text below it. Is this possible or you can add text only above the checklist?

Comment: Welcome. You are more likely to get useful help if you post your code

Comment: I want to know if it is any option that can add the text below the checklist. The command syntax is : dialog --checklist    <text> <height> <width> <list height> <tag1> <item1> <status1>...